# Can't get Facebook like box code to work on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

This is the code being generated.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);}(document));</script><div class="fb-like-box" datahref="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Taylor-Made-Services/177805802285173" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

I've been trying to get it to work for 4 hours, and I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a copy-paste error, but I suspect that datahref should be data-href.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any [Open Graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) on your pages? There are some required tags to get Facebook like buttons to work with FBML. Otherwise you may be able to use the iframe version and get it to work. Or maybe try using the like button through something like [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) which doesn't require open graph tags for it to work because they handle the scripting.

Answer (score 0):

change //connect.facebook.net to http://connect.facebook.net